# MyEclipse 10 does not start "Java was started but returned exit code 13"

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I saw that there are few topics with the same exception, but the solutions does not work on my side.

My specs:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Java 1.6.0_33 64 bit installed (Path-Variable is set)
- MyEclipse 10 installed

Some days ago it worked all fine. Now I wanted to start it, then it shows the following error. Sadly I cannot attach images here, because of my low reputation. But the error "Java was started but returned exit code 13" occurs

This is the content of the myeclipse.ini

```
#utf8 (do not remove)
-clean
-startup
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v201201111650
-install
k:\devel\Genuitec\MyEclipse 10
-vm
c:\java\bin\javaw.exe
-configuration
k:\devel\Genuitec\MyEclipse 10\configuration
-vmargs
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

The only thing what I have done since it worked the last time, I installed python and updated the path varable. I read that the path variable can be the reason but I checked it and could not see anything bad. Does someone know what the reason could be.

Thanks

- Content of Path-Variable :C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.5-Q16;c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.5-Q16;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\9.0\DLLShared\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\lib;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\TC UP\PLUGINS\Library;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%/bin;%PYTHON_HOME%;%PYTHON_HOME%/Scripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### What is the cause of this error ?

From **[here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html)** :

> this error is caused when you are attempting to start Eclipse using
>   the wrong version of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

### Possible Fixes/problems

#### 1.

Try starting eclipse with hardcoded 64-bit JVM as follows :

`eclipse -vm C:/java/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`

---

#### 2.

**From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587518/eclipse-error-on-startup-windows-7)** 
Remove the launcher.library from your eclipse.ini. Delete the following bit from the eclipse.ini :

```
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v201201111650
```

---

#### 3.

**From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587518/eclipse-error-on-startup-windows-7)** 
Try using the full path to the jvm.dll instead of the exe files, like so :

```
-vm 
C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

---

#### 4.

**[Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781124/eclipse-helios-not-launching)** Using an x86 Eclipse with a x64 JDK.
**Fix** Just point to a JDK with the same architecture as your Eclipse in your eclipse.ini file, eg:

```
-vm
c:/java/jdk1.6.0_25_x86/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

Please check the version of the JDK in the path like so by typing `java -version`. On Windows 7, 64 bit with JDK 1.6.0_30 I get the following output :

[image]

Notice the `64-Bit Server VM` in the last line. Do you get this ?

See this page : 
[Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

---

#### 5.

If you Eclipse folder is on a path with spaces, try moving it to a simple path such as directly to c:/eclipse.

From here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843744/325742

> I had the eclipse folder on my desktop and it gave me this error
>
> I simply moved the eclipse folder to program files and it worked, no
>   idea why

Comment: I tried it already with an 32 bit java but it also not worked, its really strange. Because it worked previously, also I installed the newest jdk to c:\java The JAVA_HOME points to c:\java

Comment: @AlPhaba, try removing the launcher.library from your eclipse.ini as indicated above ?

Comment: @AlPhaba , can you please tell us the version of JAVA that you are using ? I agree that it has suddenly stopped working. Did you move the MyEclipse folder around ?

Comment: @AlPhaba, please post the output of `java -version` ?

Comment: @AlPhaba , I have numbered my suggestions above. Please tell us which of the above you have tried.

Comment: Thanks!!! As I read "did you move the installation" there I found it. I am working with subst command in windows to map a drive as my development drive. This was the problem, I mapped a similiar one with an older copy of eclipse. Now I mapped the correct drive and changed the paths in the ini, then it worked

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this fix! #3 worked for me. I was using /client/jvm.dll instead of /server/jre.dll

Comment: I had this issue, 2 version of JAVA were installed on my computer, thx for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

Following 2 things worked for me.

1)Make sure your JAVA_HOME path is set to JDK and JAVA_HOME is included in PATH.

2) Add first two lines of following code in STS.ini . It should look like below.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.My problem was solved after I downloaded and installed jre7 and pointed -vm to the javaw.exe in eclipse.ini
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

I had Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the parameters in .ini file but it still didn't work. Just install 32 bit along with 64 bit version of JDK and it will work.

Note: my eclipse folder is in c:/

Answer (score 0):

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)
did work for me.
There's a way to configure the eclipse.ini file and that's explained in the first answer you will see in that post.

Albert.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading the right JDK for "EclipseLuna".
Hope it helps: [JDK_FROM_ORACLE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Then you have to choose the version that fits in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
"Java was started but returned exit code 13" error code;
```

For me, this problem was started after installing another version jdk. I have seen eclipse log file in  configuration folder:

error was this following:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
```

I removed java path from class path and eclipse runts successfully; Path was this:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Answer (score 0):

@Harshit Solution Worked for me.

1)Make sure your JAVA_HOME path is set to JDK and JAVA_HOME is included in PATH.

2) But i  Add first two lines of following code in AppceleratorStudio.ini not in STS.ini . It should look like below.

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe