# Eclipse gives “Java was started but returned exit code 13”

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

All hell broke loose after i uninstalled my java 6 and installed java 7 (both jdk and jre). On opening eclipse it gave the error that "No JVM found at.....". So, i explicitly gave the location of javaw.exe as

```
-vm
```

C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

in the eclipse.ini file. Now it says "Java was started but returned exit code 13".
Also, in the elispse.ini file i changed
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
to 
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7

There are many solutions online like :

[MyEclipse 10 does not start "Java was started but returned exit code 13"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846758/myeclipse-10-does-not-start-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

but none of them works. Any insight?

Comment: Eclipse and Java have to both be 32-bit or both be 64-bit.

Comment: @nitind I switched my path from `C:\Program Files (x86)` to `C:\Program Files` and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

if you have updated your `jdk` to 7 you are most likely to face this problem.

This happens mainly due to:

1. incompatible `sdk` and `jdk` versions
2. using a 32 bit java version for your 64 bit eclipse `JVM` (`programfilex86-java`)

WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO :
firstly check the `eclipse.ini` file to see if you have a path that is pointing to your `jdk`
it should look something like this

```
-vm    
C:\Program Files\Java\blah\blah\blah\javaw.exe
```

if not then locate the `jdk` 7 `javaw.exe` file
sample :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

paste `-vm` and the path below it into your `eclipse.ini` file

```
-vm  
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

make sure that you type the above just before the `-vmargs` and after the `OpenFile`

Comment: also had to change my Environment Variables then it worked

Comment: seems I have this error every now and then. my 32bit path ddnt change anything but the 64bit path did since I have both JAVAs installed

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much

Comment: It worked, but not for ** jdk1.6.0_24** ,still dont know y

Comment: it worked for me by adding above two lines. thank you

Answer (score 29):

This problem happened  because  either  u  install new version of  jdk  so you have both 32bit version and 64bit

how to solve the  problem  is just go open computer  & go to c then you will see 
[image: location]

after that you probably  use 32 bit so just  chose C:\Program Files
and there you will find folder called  java

in it 
[image: location 2]

so you have many different version of  jdk  so easily chose jre7
and to  to  bin and you will find  javaw.exe in it  like 
[image: loaction 3]

now only just  take that path copy  and  go to start type  eclipse.ini you will see text file  just  open it  and before -vmargs

write -vm  enter  path like photo 
[image: finally]

now  just open eclipse again and  have fun :D

Comment: This worked for me..

Answer (score 22):

The solution can be found [here](http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/)

The `eclipse.ini` file should be somewhat like this...

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
adtproduct
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Answer (score 21):

In your eclipse.ini file simply put

```
–vm
/home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/bin(Your path to JDK 7)
```

before `-vmargs` line.

Comment: i think the path should be upto javaw.exe not just bin..... anyways its still giving the same error...

Comment: thanks. this seems like what I was missing. also my .ini said `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6` which i changed to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. i was using windows8 with 64 bit OS. I just changed the path to Program Files(*86) and then it started work.
I put this line in eclipse.ini file like,

```
-vm
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: you should type this above before the -vmargs

Answer (score 6):

It would be the 32 bit version of eclipse , for instance if you are running the 32 bit version of eclipse in 64 bit JVM, this error will be the result.

To confirm this check for log in your configuration folder of the eclipse. Log will be as following 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM ...

try installing the either 64 bit eclipse or run in 32 bit jvm

Comment: This turned out to be my issue. I had installed 64 bit Eclipse and 32 bit JDK. Installing 64 bit JDK and pointing `-vm` in `eclipse.ini` to that fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, correct!. I also had Eclipse 32bit on 64 JVM, Dowloaded 64bit Eclipse and walla! perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I installed 32 bits ADT and It works fine without changing my configuration (Windows 7 64 bits, Java 6 32 bits).

Answer (score 2):

[image]I got this fixed by doing the below steps,

1. The eclipse finds the JAVA executables from
   'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath'

   2.The folder structure will contain shortcuts to the below executables, 
   i. java.exe
   ii. javaw.exe
   iii. javaws.exe 
   3.For me the executable paths were pointing to my (ProgramFiles(x84)) folder location
2. I corrected it to Program Files path(64 bit) and the issue got resolved

Please find the screenshot for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening eclipse.exe , first open folder named configuration then you will get log file like 1401241141809.log ; open that log (open latest one) detail error will be listed there.
Ex:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM

means you need to have JVM and SDK of same version.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue by changing JDK1.8 64bit version to JDK 1.8 32bit(x86) version

Answer (score 1):

Check you PATH environment variable once. Make sure the correct location of your JDK is specified there.

Answer (score 0):

When I uninstalled Java 8 it worked fine.

Comment: first of all we have to check and confirm how many versions of java are installed in our machine, this might help to filter majority of the conflicts.