# Eclipse Kepler, Java was Started but returned Exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I Have been Facing Problem with Eclipse with the Following Error:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Googling "java exit code 13" returns a ton of results. What happened when you tried some of those suggestions?

Comment: Read the following threads, same Q has been asked multiple times. IF this doesnt help then consider asking:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846758/myeclipse-10-does-not-start-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721290/eclipse-gives-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724839/on-starting-eclipse-it-gives-an-error-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion , but I already Googled my Question and was unable to fix my problem ,so I turned to SO.

Comment: First you should  set environment variable to Windows properties variable name = PATH variable value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin not to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin.

and Then go to  eclipse.ini  and add the line --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: Please let me know, if you still lost.. I can guide through the steps of setting up environment variable and the rest of the steps

Comment: PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;C:\Python33;C:\Program Files\nodejs" I already got my Path right,.

Comment: Also Added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe to ini...Doesnt work ....-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe ...  "Could'nt create java Virtual machine"

Comment: You have a 64-bit Eclipse. Any Java that installed by default into "c:\Program Files (x86)" is 32-bit. They need to match. Where is the javaw.exe, and can you paste the contents of the eclipse.ini?