# Downloaded Java 7 Eclipse doesn't start

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-7

Ok, so I've been using eclipse Luna for a bit now with the Java 6 and all.  Today, I decided it was time to update to Java 7.  I did so by going to the Oracle site, downloading the Java 7 run time environment, and it said it would install.  I let it install, but it told me that it detected previous versions of java (java 6) that it wanted to uninstall.  I don't know a lot about the process and assumed it was fine and this probably isn't the problem anyway.  But it installed, and when I tried to run things in eclipse, it gave me an error.  So I restarted Eclipse.  Suddenly, it wouldn't start giving me the error code 13.  Then, I re installed Eclipse Luna.  Now I get the same error and am worried I totally screwed up my Java.  Can you help? I can also post the error report it gives me.

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/Javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32x86_64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1608.dll
-startup
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2b0_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dogsi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar
C:/Users/Jared/Downloads/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

If I check my java version via command prompt, it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Jared>java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I have minimal knowledge on this process however, if my educated guess is right, Luna is based on 1.6-1.7 and since I apparently have 1.8.0_31, I need a more updated version.

If you know how to help, please explain thoroughly, so I can understand as much as possible
Thanks in advance

-Jared.

Comment: No, luna is fine for 8. Sounds like you need to add 8 to luna.

Comment: How would I go about doing this, @ChiefTwoPencils ?

Comment: Why is this tagged java-8

Comment: @mjs it's because I have java-8 installed, so people with knowledge on operating IDEs with java-8 can help as well as those who have knowledge with java 7

Comment: Did you also install JDK 8? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @sukhoi191 I am reattempting

Comment: @JaredMassa It's necessary to install correct JDK version as well, if you're going to compile programs written in Java. Maybe you've tried to install 64-bit version on 32-bit system?

Comment: @sukhoi191 I have a 64-bit system.  The installation wizard began, however bear in mind that its not compilation that is an issue yet, my eclipse environment cannot fully begin, and presents me with the error I typed out.  I haven't yet gotten to the stage of java code compilation yet.

Comment: @JaredMassa Good point, although take a look at your error message: `Java was started but returned exit code=13`. It seems like a problem with Java to me, not with eclipse itself. There were some similar issues on SO, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846758/myeclipse-10-does-not-start-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13, you can check them in the meantime.

Comment: @sukhoi191 I figured it out, it was a problem with my installation of the JDK, and was solved upon my re-installation, so please could you post this as an answer so I can give you correct credit.

Comment: @JaredMassa I'm glad you solved this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also install correct JDK version.