# Error When I Start Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/:/usr/lib/jni
-Djava.class.path=/home/giri/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/giri/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/giri/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/giri/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/giri/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/:/usr/lib/jni
-Djava.class.path=/home/giri/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Eclipse Helios not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781124/eclipse-helios-not-launching)

> This occurs when using an x86 Eclipse with a x64 JDK (and perhaps
>   vice-versa). Just point to a JDK with the same architecture as your
>   Eclipse in your eclipse.ini file, eg:
>
> `-vm /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_25_x86/jre/bin/javaw.exe`